# Update all record expect for one record which shares same key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table where few records shares same sales_key. I need to update the amount columns to 0 except for one record which have sales_key. Meaning for each sales_key, only one record should have amount, other record need to be zero.

[image]

I have tried using min but no luck.

```
UPDATE #TEMPSALES2
SET NET_TTL = CASE 
                WHEN QTY = (SELECT MIN(QTY) FROM #TEMPSALES2 AS t2 WHERE t2.SALES_KEY = #TEMPSALES2.SALES_KEY) AND PRD_CD = (SELECT MIN(PRD_CD) FROM #TEMPSALES2 AS t2 WHERE t2.SALES_KEY = #TEMPSALES2.SALES_KEY)  THEN NET_TTL
                ELSE 0
               END,
NET_TTL_TAX = CASE 
                WHEN QTY = (SELECT MIN(QTY) FROM #TEMPSALES2 AS t2 WHERE t2.SALES_KEY = #TEMPSALES2.SALES_KEY) AND PRD_CD = (SELECT MIN(PRD_CD) FROM #TEMPSALES2 AS t2 WHERE t2.SALES_KEY = #TEMPSALES2.SALES_KEY) THEN NET_TTL_TAX
                ELSE 0
               END,
MKT_TAX_AMT = CASE 
                WHEN QTY = (SELECT MIN(QTY) FROM #TEMPSALES2 AS t2 WHERE t2.SALES_KEY = #TEMPSALES2.SALES_KEY) AND PRD_CD = (SELECT MIN(PRD_CD) FROM #TEMPSALES2 AS t2 WHERE t2.SALES_KEY = #TEMPSALES2.SALES_KEY) THEN MKT_TAX_AMT
                ELSE 0
               END
```

Comment: "only one record should have amount" which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to uniquely identify each record. If you added an id column to your temp table then we could number the records within each Sale_Key group  and update any record beyond the first

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPSALES2 
(
    SALES_KEY   VARCHAR(512),
    NET_TTL smallmoney,
    NET_TTL_TAX smallmoney,
    MKT_TAX_AMT smallmoney,
    ID INT
);

INSERT INTO TEMPSALES2 (SALES_KEY, NET_TTL, NET_TTL_TAX, MKT_TAX_AMT,ID) VALUES
    ('1', '1.12', '2.12', '3.12',1),
    ('1', '1.12', '2.12', '3.12',2),
    ('2', '4.12', '5.12', '6.12',3),
    ('3', '7.12', '8.12', '9.12',4);

SELECT * FROM  TEMPSALES2

--Add row number for Sales_Key column
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SALES_KEY ORDER BY SALES_KEY ASC) AS RowNum  FROM  TEMPSALES2

--Update all rows beyond the first one in each Sales Key group 
UPDATE TEMPSALES2
  SET NET_TTL =0, NET_TTL_TAX=0, MKT_TAX_AMT=0
WHERE ID in 
(
 SELECT ID FROM
  (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SALES_KEY ORDER BY SALES_KEY ASC) AS RowNum  FROM  TEMPSALES2
  ) t
  WHERE ROWNUM > 1
)


SELECT * FROM  TEMPSALES2
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IyfK3hA0)

| SALES_KEY | NET_TTL | NET_TTL_TAX | MKT_TAX_AMT | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1200 | 2.1200 | 3.1200 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 0.0000 | 2 |
| 2 | 4.1200 | 5.1200 | 6.1200 | 3 |
| 3 | 7.1200 | 8.1200 | 9.1200 | 4 |

Comment: You don't need a join, you can update directly through a CTE, view or derived table.

Comment: I simplified the solution using Charlieface idea of a CTE https://dbfiddle.uk/IyYKE16z

Answer (score 0):

You can update using a CTE and window functions

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SALES_KEY ORDER BY SomeOtherColumn) AS rn
    FROM #TEMPSALES2
)
UPDATE cte
SET NET_TTL = 0
WHERE rn > 1;
```